# Memory usage by const declared variable

Tags: c#, memory, constants

If I declare variable in class as const, and create multiple instances of this class, variable will be copied for each instance or not?

Comment: If something is constant, it is perfectly safe and reasonable to share it, which is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
`const` fields are implicitly `static`.

Comment: Are they `static` or "implicitly like static"?

Comment: Implicitly static, meaning that the compiler makes these variables `static` behind the curtain.  See [Jon Skeet's answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-can-t-i-use-code-static-code-and-code-const-code-together.aspx)